# Adding Object to nested array in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I found lot's of solutions online, but I've done my best for a week and found no way to solve it. I believe the fault to be the **reducer ADD_GOAL**, that is why i left it empty.

Thanks alot! :)

I want to add objects to the **goals array**. I always want to initialize goals empty, but I want to be able to add and remove objects freely. The idea is to save the objects like this.

```
{
  list: {
    '0': {
      id: 0,
      dueDate: 'By May 28th I Will have: ',
      goals: [
        {0: {...}
         1: {...}
         3: {...}
}
      ]
    }
   '1':{
      id: 0,
      dueDate: 'By June 31st I Will have: ',
      goals: [
        {2: {...}
         4: {...}
  }
}
```

### Reducer

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
  let copyList = [{ description: '213', aim: 12, progress: 2, percentage: 20 }];
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_DUEDATE':
      return { ...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload }
    case 'ADD_GOAL':
      return {

      }
    case 'DELETE_TODO':
      return state.filter((item, index) => index !== action.payload)
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

### Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class List extends React.Component {
  state = {
    id: 0,
    goalId: 0
  }

  createDueDate = () => {
    this.props.add({
      id: this.state.id,
      dueDate: "By May 28th I Will do something: ",
      goals: [{}]
    })
    this.setState({ id: this.state.id + 1 });
  }

  addGoal = () => {
    this.props.addToList({
      goals:
        [{ id: this.state.goalId, description: '213', aim: 12, progress: 2, percentage: 20 }]
    })
    this.setState({ goalId: this.state.goalId + 1 })

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <button className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={this.createDueDate}></button>
        </div>

        <div>
          <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.addGoal}></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    list: state.list
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    add: (value) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'ADD_DUEDATE', payload: value })
    },
    get: (id) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'GET_DUEDATE', payload: id })
    },
    addToList: (value) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'ADD_GOAL', payload: value })
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(List);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Trigger a re-render when a new goal is added and update the UI?

Comment: I am trying to add objects to the goals array by clicking a button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume a nested array of items in our reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    items : {
        deepItem  :[1, 2, 2],
        reallyDeepItem: {
            a : [1,2,3]
            b : {'a', 'c'}
        }
    }
}
```

And now let's assume 2 actions, one to add an item on `state.items.deepItem` that we're gonna call `ADD_DEEP_ITEM` and another one to insert an item on `state.items.reallyDeepItem.a` called `ADD_DEEPER_ITEM`. Let's write our reducer:

```
const Reducer = (state = initialState, action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_DEEP_ITEM': return {
            ...state,
            items : {
                ...state.items,
                deepItem : state.items.deepItem.concat(action.data)
            }
        }

        case 'ADD_DEEPER_ITEM': return{
            ...state,
            items :{
                ...state.items,
                reallyDeepItem:{
                    ...state.items.reallyDeepItem,
                    a : state.itens.reallyDeepItem.a.concat(action.data)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's it, properly updated! Just remember to always spread all properties and then override the ones you want.

Comment: in case of "'ADD_DEEP_ITEM'" even we are using spread operator .reference of a and b will still point to old state reference  as they are objects and not primitive type. by using spread operator  reference of "reallyDeepItem" will be copied only . let me now my undestanding is correct or not ?